# cyBrowser for cytoscape can't loading any graph plots

Tags: cytoscape

I have any problem with cytoscape, actually cyBrowser. It doesn't work correct.
There are 3 different shapes:

1. I actually work at my windows 10 PC and cyBrowser during create any graph plots (specifically heat map) isn't loading (I can see 100% processing, but but nothing happens);
2. In addition I use MacOS PC on work and and everything is fine there;
3. Actually I use MacAir and I have problem with cytoscape work when I use cy browser - it's just crushing
   If you can help me, I will be extremely grateful

Answer (score 1):

OK, there are a couple of quick work-arounds.  First, when you create your plots, you should see an html file in your home directory. This is created by cyPlot when you request the plot to be created as a debugging aid.  You should just be able to open that in any browser and you'll have your plot.

Second, you should be able to disable the use of cyBrowser and use a native browser instead, although certain things won't work (e.g. selection in the browser won't be reflected in Cytoscape).  To do this, go to Edit->Preferences->Properties and look for "useCyBrowser" and set that to false.